# interesting select box case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok i am trying to make a select box like this used in following website
http://www.buildasign.com/PowerDesign.aspx?T=72486B387A61516563704442304E344F3068766947673D3D

When you will open the website link you will see a default word "Go" as selected. On left 
side of drawing window there is size option which is of 91 value. But there are some fix values in select which never change like 8,10,12. How he is keeping one field which doesn't show in select(This value 91 doesnot show in dropdown) but still appears in it. Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: Are you sure that is select/option tags? I doubt it! ;)

Comment: @PedramBehroozi i am trying to do it using select/options tag.

Answer (score 1):

In a browser such as chrome, inspect the element and you'll see the text "91" is in a textbox, overlaid over the dropdown list. This simulates a combobox. There are various combobox jQuery plugins: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/combobox

Answer (score 1):

It's not a standard select box. But a textbox with some predefined text that is shown as an AJAX select box (a .NET control renderes data as a select box but it's not HTML select form element! just looks like it).

Answer (score 1):

## Spolto is pretty dead on with this one.  The author of the site just set the text that way.

If you notice, the "drop-down" is still text typable, so despite the options you can type any set of digits there!